# Detect click outside of Angular application which runs in an iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, click

I'm developing an Angular App which is embedded in a Wordpress page. I'm using an iframe to embedd the Angular App into the Worpress page. Now I have modal dialogs in my Angular App which should be closed when clicking outside the dialogs. That works fine when the click happens outside the dialog and inside the Angular App. But when the click goes even outside the iframe, somewhere else on the wordpress page, nothing happens. It seems like all clicks outisde the iframe are not recognized by the Angular event handlers.
I've found some solutions for Javascript where the page outside of the iframe was referenced through `document.parentElement`. In my case that doesn't seem to work, the parentElement of my document is `undefined`.
I hope you understand what my problem is, it would be quite some effort to put up a running example.

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean... would you expect that work just like that? An iFrame is like a browser inside a browser and fairly much isolated. If the iframe is a different domain than the parent, you can't use direct forms of communicating either. The only way to solve this is to have a listener in the parent - and pass this to the iFrame using mechanisms like postMessage. This is why iFrames suck really ;-)

Comment: Maybe there is a simpeler way now I come to think of it... but it's not ideal. You COULD try to detect a window blur inside your angular application and close the modal then..  But the side-effect might be that it closes 'too easily'..

Comment: You can use angular zone for this  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.document.addEventListener(
            'click',
            this.onDocumentClick.bind(this)
        );
    });

Comment: @MikeOne: In my case both is running on the same domain. I could build some sort of backend which enables communication between both, but I was hoping for an easier / leightweight solution. What do you mean by try to detect a window blur? You mean the wordpress page tries do detect window blur in the Angular App?

Comment: @MskSatheesh I tried your solution, but doesn't work. The 'onDocumentClick' method only fires when the click is inside my Angular App. Clicks outside are still not recognized.

Comment: Well.. the idea was that a click outside of the iframe - would cause a blur event inside the iframe which you can listen to inside your angular app..

Comment: But if they do run on the same domain.. I can imagine you could have access to window.parent..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Msk Satheesh and @MikeOne, with the hints of both of you guys combined I got it running!
The thing is that I can really address the (outer) wordpress page by `window.parent`. But this only works because both run in the same domain. Combined with the code Msk Satheesh posted in his first comment it works. And I don't even need to run anything outside of Angular. In my modal dialog component in Angular I put the following code:

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ResultsDialogComponent>, private eRef: ElementRef) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!this.onDocumentClickFunction){
      this.onDocumentClickFunction = this.onDocumentClick.bind(this);
    }
    window.parent.addEventListener( 'click', this.onDocumentClickFunction ); 
  }

  onDocumentClick() {    
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.eRef.nativeElement.click();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.parent.removeEventListener( 'click', this.onDocumentClickFunction ); 
  }
```

And that's it. The elegant thing is that the `onDocumentClick()` only fires if the click is outside the iFrame. That means I don't need additional logic to find out if the click is inside or outside the iFrame. The line `this.eRef.nativeElement.click();` is necessary to bring back the focus to the iFrame. Without that line the modal only disappears if the user clicks into the iFrame himself.

Answer (score -1):

**Try Using:**

**Angular Component**

```
   constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
       window['clickEvent'] = (event) => {
           zone.run(() => {
               console.log(event);
           });
       };
   }
```

**Outer Js:**

```
onClickEvent(event){
     window.parent.frames[#frameId].clickEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought you just turned your earlier comment into an answer.

Comment: This one I didn't get to work. The ´line window['clickEvent'] = (event) => ...´ was marked as error by VS Code. But your comment on my original post helped a lot, thanks!